# Creating a new Postgres Scheme for Offer-Ready in Azure Cloud - "Non empty schema"

Tags: postgresql, azure, flyway

I tried to build an Offer-Ready Docker container on Azure Cloud. Although I created a new (blank) table in PostgreSQL, I got this strange error message.

> javax.servlet.ServletException: org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder$1: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Found non-empty schema(s) "public" without schema history table! Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.

I double-checked the database, there is no table in schema "public". I didn't have that problem on AWS. Has anybody an idea what is different on Azure?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience once.

- The PostgreSQL database on Azure seemed empty (`\dt` returned no results),
- But Flyway claimed the database was not empty (and therefore would not apply the migration scripts, for fear of interfering with whatever was already there).

Here is what I did was:

1. Create a new schema within the database e.g. `myschema`
2. Delete the default schema called `public`
3. Add the parameter `currentSchema=myschema` to the JDBC URL

And then it worked. I never got to find out what the root cause of this problem was.

EDIT: This link might provide more information on what objects are in the "public" schema by default on Azure PostgreSQL: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Re-quot-database-that-is-not-empty-quot-when-trying-to-use-azure/qaq-p/1308795/comment-id/410329#M410329